# Reading large text files line-by-line is still using all my memory

Tags: python, file, optimization, text

I'm writing a simple program that is supposed to read a large file (263.5gb to be exact) with JSON on each line ([link here](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/3mg812/full_reddit_submission_corpus_now_available_2006/)). I've done some research and the best method I've found is to read each line by line. Mine looks like this ([full code here](https://trinket.io/python/4d1aa528e4)):

```
with open(dumpLocation, "r") as f:
for line in f:

    # Read line, convert to dictionary and assign it to 'c'
    c = json.loads(f.readline())

    for n in files:
        if n.lower() in c["title"].lower():

            try:
                # Collect data
                timestamp = str(c["retrieved_on"])
                sr_id = c["subreddit_id"]
                score = str(c["score"])
                ups = str(c["ups"])
                downs = str(c["downs"])
                title = ('"' + c["title"] + '"')

                # Append data to file
                files[n].write(timestamp + ","
                               + sr_id + ","
                               + score + ","
                               + ups + ","
                               + downs + ","
                               + title + ","
                               + "\n")
                found += 1
            except:
                numberOfErrors += 1
                errors[comments] = sys.exc_info()[0]

        comments += 1

        # Updates user
        print("Comments scanned: " + str(comments) + "\nFound: " + str(found) + "\n")
```

Now I can get this to run, and it ran for a good hour before it crashed (approximately 1.3 million lines). I noticed in the processes that the memory usage was slowly growing and got to about 2gb before crashing.

There is approximately 200 million lines I need to sort through, and I am also writing to files if specific words are found (searched for 5, found 337 before crash). Is there a better way of doing this? My computer usually only has about 2gb RAM to spare

Comment: Why do you call `f.readline()` when you already have the line in the variable `line`?

Comment: I completely missed that, thanks! Accidentally left it there when I was changing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a memory leak here:

```
except:
    numberOfErrors += 1
    errors[comments] = sys.exc_info()[0]
```

With a huge number of input lines, number of errors can also be huge, especially if you have some error in your algorithm.

Plain `except` is evil because it hides all errors, even syntax errors in your code. You should handle only specific exception types that you expect to happen on real data, and make try-except block as narrow as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I had the feeling there was something small compounding, had no idea it would be this though...

Comment: @TylerB Please accept the answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: It appears to be just as memory hungry as before and increasing at about 1.5mb/sec

Answer (score 0):

I worked out where the memory leak was. On this line where I was printing to the console after every line:

```
 print("Comments scanned: " + str(comments) + "\nFound: " + str(found) + "\n")
```

Print 200 million times and your computer is bound to run out of memory trying to hold it all in the console at once. Removed it and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Typically your console should have a scrollback limit after which the history ages off. If it doesn't, you might consider setting one. For Windows, in the command prompt properties, under `Layout`, adjust the Screen Buffer Size. On Linux, it depends hugely on the terminal host you're using; you'd want to search for "scrollback buffer <name of your terminal>" there to figure out how to limit it.